# Is it possible to pause jobs submitted via qsub?

Tags: batch-jobs

I am running my jobs on a small cluster. I submitted them via `qsub`. Now my labmates need resources more urgently than me, so I need to either kill my jobs or pause them, if possible.

Is there a way of pausing my jobs and releasing the CPU, RAM, etc.?

I am a normal user (no root privileges).

Comment: You can hold back your not yet running jobs with `qhold`, but this does not affect already running jobs. It seems that `qmod` can suspend running jobs, but needs root or manager privileges.

Comment: Assuming you have MOAB cluster: you can suspend your job (if configured accordingly), but only administrator can resume it: http://docs.adaptivecomputing.com/mwm/Content/topics/jobAdministration/suspendresume.html

Comment: use `qrls <job ID>` to rerun your job.

Answer (score 10):

If the jobs haven't started you can put them on hold with [`qhold`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/qhold). Use [`qrls`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/qrls) to restart.

```
qhold <job ID>
qrls <job ID>
```

If they are already running you can use [`qsig`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/qsig) to suspend and resume jobs (you may need extra permissions for that, ask your administrator if that's the case):

```
qsig -s suspend <job ID>
qsig -s resume <job ID>
```

Once you have resumed your job you may have to force it to run with [`qrun`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/qrun)

```
qrun <job ID>
```

Tested on a SLES 11 SP4 system with PBSPro 13.0.2.153173, but I am confident it should work with other POSIX-compliant batch job submission systems.